# How can I erase all overlapping length from a two layers of MULTILINESTRING in R?

Tags: r, r-sf

In R, I have a layer of lines that I upload, then extend them in a pre-set distance in both directions to create a second layer of lines. After extending these lines, I'd like to create a third layer that is just the extension of the lines; essentially the difference between the first and second layers. Below is an example of the code I use to extend the original lines in two directions:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(raster)
library(data.table)
library(reshape)
library(dplyr)
library(stars)
library(mapview)

sf_use_s2(FALSE) # To deal with spherical nature of some data we're working with

################################################################################
#               SETTING DIRECTORY AND READING IN DATA                          #
my_lines <- tibble("ID" = c("A","A","A","B","B", "C","C") , X=  c(647851,647875,647875,647766,647766,647826,647822) , 
                   Y=c(6859335,6859318,6859319,6859028,6859030,6859314,6859316) )

my_lines <- my_lines %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("X", "Y")) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize() %>%
  st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") %>% 
  st_set_crs("+init=epsg:2154") %>% 
  st_transform(crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

mapview(my_lines)

############## NOW, EXTENDING THE LINES ###################

# First, creating a function to determine which direction each end is pointing
st_ends_heading <- function(line)
{
  M <- sf::st_coordinates(line)
  i <- c(2, nrow(M) - 1)
  j <- c(1, -1)
  
  headings <- mapply(i, j, FUN = function(i, j) {
    Ax <- M[i-j,1]
    Ay <- M[i-j,2]
    Bx <- M[i,1]
    By <- M[i,2]
    unname(atan2(Ay-By, Ax-Bx))
  })
  
  return(headings)
}

# Second, a function which extends the line in a direction by a set distance
st_extend_line <- function(line, distance, end = "BOTH")
{
  if (!(end %in% c("BOTH", "HEAD", "TAIL")) | length(end) != 1) stop("'end' must be 'BOTH', 'HEAD' or 'TAIL'")
  
  M <- sf::st_coordinates(line)[,1:2]
  keep <- !(end == c("TAIL", "HEAD"))
  
  ends <- c(1, nrow(M))[keep]
  headings <- st_ends_heading(line)[keep]
  distances <- if (length(distance) == 1) rep(distance, 2) else rev(distance[1:2])
  
  M[ends,] <- M[ends,] + distances[keep] * c(cos(headings), sin(headings))
  newline <- sf::st_linestring(M)
  
  # If input is sfc_LINESTRING and not sfg_LINESTRING
  if (is.list(line)) newline <- sf::st_sfc(newline, crs = sf::st_crs(line))
  
  return(newline)
}

# Preserving data frame format to append shortly
new_lines <- as.data.frame(my_lines[1,])

# Loop through each line in the polyline layer
for (i in seq_len(nrow(my_lines))) {
  # Get the i-th line in the polyline layer
  line <- my_lines[i,]
  
  # Now, actually extending
  sf::st_geometry(line) <- st_extend_line(sf::st_geometry(line), 0.00139)
  
  new_lines <- rbind(new_lines, line)
}

# Removing original observation which preserved data frame for append
new_lines = new_lines[-1,]

new_lines <- st_as_sf(new_lines)

mapview(list(new_lines, my_lines), col.regions=list("red", "blue"), col = list("red","blue"))
```

If you run the "mapview" code above, you can see an example of my data visually depcited: [image: Toy Example Map] The third layer I'm looking to create would just be the red lines in that picture, without the area overlapped by the blue lines. When I tried "st_difference", I ended up with a layer of N x N observations (N being my original number of lines), rather than 2 x N observations. Any thoughts on how I could go about this would be greatly appreciated!